# component or code for wave analyzer

Tags: delphi, audio, audio-streaming

I am searching for a component to:

- analyzing and comparing sound data
- drawing the sound histogram.

Are there any guides or other suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you update your tags with the language and platform you are using (e.g. c# & winforms)?  Thanks.

Comment: You may also mean "spectrogram" instead of "histogram", although histogram is not technically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [wavesurfer](http://www.speech.kth.se/wavesurfer/) program:

> WaveSurfer is an Open Source tool for
>   sound visualization and manipulation.
>   It has been designed to suit both
>   novice and advanced users. WaveSurfer
>   has a simple and logical user
>   interface that provides functionality
>   in an intuitive way and which can be
>   adapted to different tasks. It can be
>   used as a stand-alone tool for a wide
>   range of tasks in speech research and
>   education. Typical applications are
>   speech/sound analysis and sound
>   annotation/transcription. WaveSurfer
>   can also serve as a platform for more
>   advanced/specialized applications.
>   This is accomplished either through
>   extending the WaveSurfer application
>   with new custom plug-ins or by
>   embedding WaveSurfer visualization
>   components in other applications.

It can perform many different types of analysis, I have only used it for practicing Chinese tone pronunciation.